# how to add a toolbar divider for a three column view in swiftUI life cycle

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar, macos-big-sur, swiftui-navigationview

I am looking for a way to achieve a Toolbar for a three column layout like Mail.app. Also the Notes.app uses almost the same Toolbar with the only important difference between the two apps being that Notes.app looks like it's `WindowStyle` is a `HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle` and Mail.app looks like a `Default|TitleBarWindowStyle`.

Following should be true:

1. If the sidebar is collapsed there is a list and detail view
2. The dividing line that separates the list from the detail view goes all the way up through the toolbar. (This could be achieved with a `HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle`)
   [image: sidebar collapsed - fully divided view]
3. If the Title is too long to fit into the navigation list, the vertical dividing line will be broken: The list is still divided from the Detail View as before, but now the Toolbar looks like a `DefaultWindowStyle` with only a small `Divider()`-like line in the Toolbar.
   [image: sidebar collapsed - divider line]

Which combination of `WindowStyle`, `WindowToolbarStyle` and `.toolbar` configuration do I need to achieve this setup?

## EDIT

I noticed that it is not possible to remove the divider line that Notes.app shows. I have not found a references to any such element in the docs though.

[image: Notes.app Customizable Toolbar]

### Code Example

I have distilled the problem down to a simple app with mostly toolbar content. In my original code I use two nested `NavigationView`s, while for the example I used only one `NavigationView` with two Lists. However the `Toolbar` results are the same.

#### Toolbar with `DefaultWindowStyle`

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ToolbarTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(titleBarIsHidden: true)
        }
        .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedWindowToolbarStyle())
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var destination: String = "Toolbar Test"
    @State var detail: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Button(action: {self.destination = "Item with the identifier:  1"}, label: {
                    Text("Item 1")
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
                Button(action: {self.destination = "Item 2"}, label: {
                    Text("Item 2")
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(text: "\(destination) – \(detail)").onAppear{self.detail = "Detail 1"},
                    label: {
                        Text("\(destination) – Detail 1")
                    })
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(text: "\(destination) – \(detail)").onAppear{self.detail = "Detail 2"},
                    label: {
                        Text("\(destination) – Detail 2")
                    })
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            Text("\(destination) – \(detail)")
        }
        .navigationTitle(destination)
        .navigationSubtitle(detail)
        .toolbar(id: "nav") {
            ToolbarItem(id: "plus", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.principal, showsByDefault: true) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {print("pressed")}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    })
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "spacer", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.confirmationAction, showsByDefault: true) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "sidebar.end", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.confirmationAction, showsByDefault: true) {
                Button(action: {print("pressed")}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.right")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example will result in a `Toolbar` that will never show the divider line that splits the whole `Toolbar` in two parts. Also the first `ToolbarItem` is positioned in the center of the `Toolbar`. I tried all `ToolbarItemPlacement` but none caused the item to move to the far left adjacent to the title.

[image: Default Window Style]

#### Toolbar with `HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle`

```swift
@main
struct ToolbarTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentViewForHiddenTitleBar()
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle()) // added hidden title style
        .windowToolbarStyle(UnifiedWindowToolbarStyle())
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViewForHiddenTitleBar: View {
    @State var destination: String = "Toolbar Test"
    @State var detail: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Button(action: {self.destination = "Item with the identifier:  1"}, label: {
                    Text("Item 1")
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
                Button(action: {self.destination = "Item 2"}, label: {
                    Text("Item 2")
                })
                .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            // add geometry reader to trim title width in toolbar
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                List {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(text: "\(destination) – \(detail)").onAppear{self.detail = "Detail 1"},
                        label: {
                            Text("\(destination) – Detail 1")
                        })
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(text: "\(destination) – \(detail)").onAppear{self.detail = "Detail 2"},
                        label: {
                            Text("\(destination) – Detail 2")
                        })
                }
                // there is no title anymore so let's fake it.
                .toolbar(id: "list navigation") {
                    ToolbarItem(id: "title", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigation, showsByDefault: true) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(destination)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            Text(detail)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .opacity(0.6)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            Text("\(destination) – \(detail)")
        }
        .navigationTitle(destination)
        .navigationSubtitle(detail)
        .toolbar(id: "nav") {
            // primary action will place the item next to the divider line.
            ToolbarItem(id: "plus", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.primaryAction, showsByDefault: true) {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {print("pressed")}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    })
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "spacer", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.confirmationAction, showsByDefault: true) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "sidebar.end", placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.confirmationAction, showsByDefault: true) {
                Button(action: {print("pressed")}, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.right")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example will result in a `Toolbar` that will always show a full height divider. Even if the title is too long. Therefore a `GeometryReader` was added. This is fine until the sidebar will collapse. The placement of `ToolbarItems` will not be correct. Also when customising the `Toolbar` there would be the possibility to remove the title, which should not be possible.

[image: Hidden Title Bar Window Style]
[image: Hidden Title Bar Window Style with Collapsed Sidebar]

Comment: Which did you try? What's wrong with each? Where is your code?

Comment: I updated the question with code examples. This might not be all the combinations I have tried so far, but these are the ones that look most promising. The `HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle` one looks like it could never reach the goal though, since the faked title seems completely wrong to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default title bar style is fine, you just need to attach your toolbar items to the subviews of your top NavigationView, e.g.:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        List {
            ...
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: { }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "sidebar.right")
                })
            }
        }
        
        List {
            ...
        }
        .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: { }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                })
            }
        }
        
        Text("\(destination) – \(detail)")
    }
    .navigationTitle(destination)
    .navigationSubtitle(detail)
}
```

I didn’t attach any toolbar items to the third column (the `Text`) but you can — just be sure to attach the same toolbar items to your DetailViews, as its toolbar will replace the Text’s toolbar when the user navigates. (if you’re not sure what I mean, just try it and you’ll quickly see what I’m talking about :)

Comment: you know what GIR... I have spent days to figure this out. with your insight is was a matter of two minutes trying until I had exactly what I was looking for. adding toolbar items to the second list and DetailView gave me exactly the split that I was looking for. Thank you so much and a hopefully happy new year to you!